# How to format numbers in legend after it has been safely used to define the legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to format the numbers tied to the legend.

This is the code that defines the legend:

```
   MapChart.prototype.addLegend = function() {
  let vis = this;

  let formatComma = d3.format(",");


  let legendData = vis.color.ticks(6).slice(0);
  let formattedLegendData = legendData.map(each => formatComma(each));

  vis.legend = vis.svg
    .selectAll(".legend")
    .data(legendData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + 20 + "," + (20 + i * 20) + ")";
    });

  vis.legend
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style("fill", vis.color);

  vis.legend
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 26)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(String);

  vis.svg
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", vis.dimensions.width + 20)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
};
```

`formattedLegendData` gives me the formatting I want but `legendData` gives me the correct colors. With `formattedLegendData`, all the legend blocks show up as black.

How can I have both, i.e. formatted legend numbers and the correct legend colors.

```
console.log(legendData); // [0, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 350000]
console.log(formattedLegendData); //["0", "50,000", "100,000", "150,000", "200,000", "250,000", "300,000", "350,000"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

You can pass `legendData` to `.data()` because your the values in `legendData` are within your scale's domain: they are numbers. Because of this, the scale (`viz.color`) returns valid colors as fills. This is why you get the correct colors here.

When you pass `formattedLegendData` to `.data()`, when you use `.style("fill", vis.color);` you pass string values to the scale. Since `"10,000"` is not likely in your domain, the scale doesn't know how to interpolate a value for the input and you get a black square.

Instead, pass the tick values directly  to `.data()`, and then apply the formatting when adding the text with something like:

```
.text(formatter)
```

As below:

```js
let color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateRdBu)
  .domain([0,5000])

let formatComma = d3.format(",");
let legendData = color.ticks(6).slice(0);

let formattedLegendData = legendData.map(each => formatComma(each));

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

let legend = svg
    .selectAll(".legend")
    .data(legendData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + 20 + "," + (20 + i * 20) + ")";
    });

  legend
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style("fill", color);

  legend
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(formatComma);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```